# продолжить выполнение цикла после неудачного завершения приложения

Tags: java

Нужно запустить парсинг на длительное время, поставил на день, но как на зло в доме что-то делают с проводкой и уже второй скачек напряжения и следственно все данные приходится заново собирать. Подскажите простое решение на примере отрывка из моего кода, чтобы продолжить выполнения цикла с потоками на тех. позициях на которых они были прерваны. Спасибо.

```
  public class ParserMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
            // Общее число сообщений
            int total_entries = 12000;
            // Кол-во потоков
            int thread_count = 25;
            // Кол-во записей на поток
            int entries_thread = total_entries / thread_count;
            // Начальный инкремент потока
            int thread_end;
            // Конечный инкремент потока
            int thread_start;

            for (int i = 1; i <= thread_count; ++i) {
                thread_end = i * entries_thread;
                thread_start = thread_end - entries_thread;
                new ParserThread(thread_start, thread_end).start();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ParserThread extends Thread {
        private int jstart;
        private int jend;

        public ParserThread(int jstart, int jend) {
            this.jstart = jstart;
            this.jend = jend;
        }

        public void run() {
            int j = this.jstart;
            int k = this.jend;

            for (; j < k; ++j) {
               // парсим, много парсим :-)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: сохранять состояние в файл?

Comment: @Vartlok да в файл, боюсь что его придется лочить на время записи, чтобы данные не потерялись, с синтаксисом знаком, но нет опыта разработки

Comment: Можно по файлу на каждый поток, лочить ничего не нужно. Набросайте на листике список тех данных, которые нужны чтобы восстановить актуальное состояние после перезапуска. Сохранять текущее состояние в файл имеет смысл не на каждой итерации, а только например каждую сотую (зависит от задачи), дабы не тормозить процесс лишними записями. Если вы беспокоитесь что во время записи в файл программа закончит работу (выключится электричество например), то записывайте данные во временный файл, а затем заменяйте основной временным.

Comment: @iksuy проще сохранить итерацию, чем запоминать все данные, которые пишутся в БД, та в свою очередь не даст повторным индексам вписаться

Comment: А что вы потом с распарсеными данными делаете? Может проще формировать очередь необработанных идентификаторов, и в каждом потоке из нее брать новый. Или вообще взять стандартные экзекуторы и набивать их runnable'ами

Comment: @zRrr простой парсинг с помощью jsoup, где j часть URL страниц, мне сложно ориентироваться в названных вами методах, любой метод - метод, лишь бы после прерывания приложения и повторного его запуска можно было бы продолжить с последнего итератора в каждом потоке. На примере простого цикла мне понятно как сделать, но как с потоками распределить непонятно...

Comment: @aliokero, если вам достаточно запомнить только итерацию, то вообще нет проблем. Задачи разные бывают, я подумал что вам распарсенные данные нужно сохранять.

Comment: @iksuy по логике, нужно каждому потоку присваивать идентификатор и сохранять в файле текущую позицию итератора в потоке и перед запуском потока сверять, позицию идентификатора  с переданным из Main класса. Но как сохранять массивы в файл и читать их посредством Java? Если кому не сложно набросайте код, чтобы можно было разобраться, все равно по началу коряво сам сделаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Набросал такой синтетический пример. `ParserState` - класс с состоянием, умеет загружать, сохранять, обновлять состояние. При загрузке состояния если не удается, возвращает `null`.
Для простоты я именую файлы с состоянием конкретного потока номером этого потока.
В `main` перед созданием каждого потока пытаемся найти сохраненное состояние, если не удается, создаем состояние с первой итерации и запускаем поток. В потоке в методе `run` на каждой итерации обновляется состояние (это можно и не делать в данном случае, а просто когда нужно сохранить устанавливать новый индекс), через каждые `BACKUP_INTERVAL` итераций сохраняет состояние. Это чисто синтетический пример, чтобы быстро показать как схематично такое делается.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ParserMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        // Общее число сообщений
        int total_entries = 12000;
        // Кол-во потоков
        int thread_count = 25;
        // Кол-во записей на поток
        int entries_thread = total_entries / thread_count;
        // Начальный инкремент потока
        int thread_end;
        // Конечный инкремент потока
        int thread_start;

        File backupDir = new File("backup/path"); //Путь к директории где будут сохранятся состояния

        for (int i = 1; i <= thread_count; ++i) {
            ParserState state = ParserState.deserialize(new File(backupDir, String.valueOf(i)));
            thread_end = i * entries_thread;
            if(state == null){
                state = new ParserState(i, thread_end - entries_thread);
            }
            new ParserThread(state, thread_end, backupDir).start();
        }
    }
}

class ParserThread extends Thread {
    private ParserState state;
    private int jend;
    private File backupDir;

    private static final int BACKUP_INTERVAL = 100;

    public ParserThread(ParserState state, int jend, File backupDir) {
        this.state = state;
        this.jend = jend;
        this.backupDir = backupDir;
    }

    public void run() {
        int j = state.iteration;
        int k = this.jend;

        for (; j < k; ++j) {
            state.update(j);

            // парсим, много парсим :-)

            if(j % BACKUP_INTERVAL == 0){
                state.serialize(backupDir);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ParserState {

    int thread;
    int iteration;

    ParserState(int thread, int iteration){
        this.thread = thread;
        this.iteration = iteration;
    }

    public void serialize(File dir){
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(dir, String.valueOf(thread)))){
            fw.write(iteration);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log error
        }
    }

    public static ParserState deserialize(File file){
        ParserState state = null;
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
            int iteration = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            state = new ParserState(Integer.parseInt(file.getName()), iteration);
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
            //Log error
        }
        return state;
    }

    public void update(int currentIteration){
        this.iteration = currentIteration;
    }

}
```

Comment: спасибо Вам за помощь!